# How to pass GZip stream IN soapclient in php

Tags: php, soap-client

Here I am using a WSDL service. Given below my  code to access the soapclient service in php:

```
$params contains an array value and in that one value contains a base_64 encoded xml data

$client = new \SoapClient($url, array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
    'trace'=>1));
$response = $client->__soapCall('my_function', array($params));
```

When I call the service the I got the error:

> stdClass Object (
> [my_functionResult] => The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream. )